# parabola focal width

Tags: graphing-functions

What is the focal width of the parabolic equation $y=x^2-8x-18$?

I have pretty much all of the other vital numbers (vertex is $(4,-34)$, focus $(4, -\frac{87} 4$)) but am having a problem figuring the focal width.

Comment: See [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/574688/what-is-the-focal-width-of-a-parabola).

Comment: I concur with the focal distance result already given by **KittyL**.  It should be commented that the $ \ y-$ coordinate you give for the focus must then be incorrect.  (It _is_ "above" the vertex, but not _that_ far up...)

Answer (score 1):

The focal width of the parabola $(x-h)^2=4p(y-k)$ is $|4p|$.

If you know the vertex, you must know how to transform it to this standard form
$$(x-4)^2=y+34$$

So the focal width is $|4p|=1$.